# Product Logos from Captured Images

Tags: logo, copyright, legal

I'm developing a logo from a photograph of some vehicles, am I allowed to use the manufacturers icon they use on the front of the vans we **own**, in our logo?

Sorry if it's a silly question, but this area of GD is very murky and it's hard to find a solid answer.

Comment: In general, if one is asking "Can I..?" because of doubts, the answer is generally No and those doubts are entirely justified.

Comment: Relevant discussion: [Can I use my own photographs of a company's product for commercial purposes?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18434/8708)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Doing this would imply some sort of affiliation with those brands and you'd be legally at risk for using them to promote your business.